# How to make a email calendar invite automatically accepted (php)?

Tags: icalendar

I'm sending a calendar invite via email but I want it automatically be accepted.

Is there something I can change in my code? My code looks like this:

```
function sendIcalEmail ($firstname, $lastname, $email, $meeting_date, $meeting_name, $meeting_duration)  {
    $from_name = “My Name”;
    $from_address = “myname@mydomain.com”;
    $subject = “Meeting Booking”; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
    $meeting_description = “Here is a brief description of my meeting\n\n”;
    $meeting_location = “My Office”; //Where will your meeting take place

    //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
    $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . ” UTC”);
    $dtstart= gmdate(”Ymd\THis\Z”,$meetingstamp);
    $dtend= gmdate(”Ymd\THis\Z”,$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
    $todaystamp = gmdate(”Ymd\THis\Z”);

    //Create unique identifier
    $cal_uid = date(’Ymd’).’T’.date(’His’).”-”.rand().”@mydomain.com”;

    //Create Mime Boundry
    $mime_boundary = “—-Meeting Booking—-”.md5(time());

    //Create Email Headers
    $headers = “From: “.$from_name.” <”.$from_address.”>\n”;
    $headers .= “Reply-To: “.$from_name.” <”.$from_address.”>\n”;

    $headers .= “MIME-Version: 1.0\n”;
    $headers .= “Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\”$mime_boundary\”\n”;
    $headers .= “Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n”;

    //Create Email Body (HTML)
    $message .= “–$mime_boundary\n”;
    $message .= “Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n”;
    $message .= “Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n”;

    $message .= “<html>\n”;
    $message .= “<body>\n”;
    $message .= ‘<p>Dear ‘.$firstname.’ ‘.$lastname.’,</p>’;
    $message .= ‘<p>Here is my HTML Email / Used for Meeting Description</p>’;
    $message .= “</body>\n”;
    $message .= “</html>\n”;
    $message .= “–$mime_boundary\n”;

    //Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage, beware of adding tabs)
    $ical =    ‘BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:’.$from_address.’
DTSTART:’.$dtstart.’
DTEND:’.$dtend.’
LOCATION:’.$meeting_location.’
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:’.$cal_uid.’
DTSTAMP:’.$todaystamp.’
DESCRIPTION:’.$meeting_description.’
SUMMARY:’.$subject.’
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR’;

    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
    $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n';
    $message .= $ical;

    //SEND MAIL
    $mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

    if($mail_sent)     {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho it is not or should not be possible to post an invite that automatically will be accepted. Instead you should inform your users that they can they can change their settings in Outlook to automatically accept (certain) invites.
Btw thanks for your snippet. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for calendar auto acceptance you should add the given lines in your code to create ics file.
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN= ExampleName1 c;EMAIL=example1@mail.com:MAILTO:example1@mail.com

ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN= ExampleName2 c;EMAIL=example2@mail.comMAILTO:example2@mail.com